# Creating image from integer pixel array

Tags: java, image, rgb

i have integer pixel array of an image with values like -1100791, -16777056 and so on.. tried with memoryimage source and toolkit method but the image obtained had colored dashes on black background. HOw to write an RGB image from pixel values.

Comment: Do you know how the pixel values are encoded in the `int` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`WritableRaster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html).

Comment: thank u... :) g.drawImage(
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
                new MemoryImageSource(w, h, pix, 0, w)),0,(side*3)+1,null) ;worked for me... :)